# How to sort custom taxonomy loop by categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom taxonomy, which has various different terms. Basically all posts from that month are assigned to a specific term, but additionally all the posts also have standard categories assigned to them.

Creating a template for the custom and tax and using a WP_Query I have managed to display all posts belonging to a specific custom tax. Now additionally I wish to sort all posts in that custom tax loop by the post categories (e.g. grouping posts by economy, politics, technology etc.). I have attempted using a nested loop, but that didnt work.

Very new to php, any help is much appreaciated.

```html
<?php

$al_cat_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
$al_cat_name = get_queried_object()->name;
?>
    <h2><?php echo $al_cat_name; ?></h2>

<?php 
    $al_tax_post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'orderby' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'ausgabe',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $al_cat_slug,
            )
        )
    );

$query = new WP_Query($al_tax_post_args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

    <section>
     <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

     <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="fonds-article">

            <h3 class="fonds-main-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        </article>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
 
   </section>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You can not do sorting _and_ output at the same time. Sort first, output second.

Comment: _“sort all posts in that custom tax loop by the post categories”_ - you mean _inside_ each of the custom taxonomies here, yes?

Comment: yes exactly inside each of the custom taxs. So instead of having just a list of all posts the economy posts would be grouped and the politics posts would be grouped etc. 
Can you please clarify how you would sort first?

Comment: Using the normal WP “loop” methods does not make much sense in such a scenario - you need to work with arrays, if you want something you can group & sort in. `WP_Query::get_posts()` allows you to get the posts as an array. You will then need to split that into sub-arrays, so that you have the data grouped by category first, then you can sort the the posts inside those sub-arrays. And then you have to re-write your output part, using nested foreach loops.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for this. I am stuck grouping the array into sub-arrays based on category. Any chance you can point me in the right direction? Would really help me out.